# tikzpicture and pdf - x axis partially disappears

Tags: pgfplots, tikz-pgf

I would like to know why the x axis partially disappears, given the following code. Is it a PDF problem? Also, is there any option to connect the midpoints automatically but not in a smooth fashion?

The code is:

```
\documentclass[landscape]{article}

\usepackage{etex}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds,fadings}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}%[show background grid]

\tikzstyle{every node}=[font=\scriptsize]

\begin{axis}[/tikz/ybar, 
ybar legend, 
xtick align=outside,
ymin=0,
axis y line*=left,
bar width=1.5cm,
axis x line*=left,
 nodes near coords= {
    \pgfmathfloattofixed{\pgfplotspointmeta} 
    \num[
        scientific-notation = fixed,
        fixed-exponent = 0,
        round-mode = places,
        round-precision = 2,
        exponent-product=\cdot
    ]{\pgfmathresult}},
enlarge x limits=false,
grid=none,   
height=6cm,
title={},
xlabel={Intervalos de Clase},
ylabel=\rotatebox{-90}{$F_{i}$},
symbolic x coords={$<11.5$,$11.5$,$14.5$,$17.5$,$20.5$,$23.5$,$>23.5$},
xtick={$11.5$,$14.5$,$17.5$,$20.5$,$23.5$},
minor x tick num=1, 
width=\textwidth]
\addplot[white,fill=white] coordinates {($<11.5$,0) ($>23.5$,0)};
\addplot[green!80!black,fill=green!40!white] coordinates {($11.5$,0.32)($14.5$,0.56)   ($17.5$,0.64) ($20.5$,0.76) ($23.5$,1.00)};
\addplot[thick,color=blue,line join=round, smooth] coordinates {($11.5$,0.32) ($14.5$,0.56) ($17.5$,0.64) ($20.5$,0.76) ($23.5$,1.00)};
\legend{}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}           

\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay]
\node[above] (red) at (0.8,2) {\footnotesize\textcolor{magenta}{Ojiva}};
\node (reddot) at (4.1,3.0) {};
\path[->, color=magenta, line width=0.75] (red) edge [out = 50, in = 145] (reddot);
\node[right] (gre) at (11.5,2.75) {\footnotesize\textcolor{cyan}{Histograma}};
\node (gredot) at (10,2.9) {};
\path[->, color=cyan, line width=0.75] (gre) edge [out = 160, in = 45] (gredot);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Try remove `[white, fill white]` from the first `addplot`

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Comment: It looks like you've got two separate accounts, which means you cannot edit your original post or leave comments. The StackExchange staff can [merge them together for you](http://tex.stackexchange.com/help/user-merge).

Answer (score 4):

The axis line is interrupted because you're drawing two bars with zero height on top of it. To fix this, one way is to say `axis on top` in the `axis` options. This will also make sure that the green bars aren't drawn on top of the axis.

It looks like you're using those empty bars only to correct the spacing. Instead of doing that, I would recommend using the `enlarge x limits` key to add extra space on the left and right of the axis.

To draw a plot consisting of straight line segments, use `sharp plot`:

[image]

```
\documentclass[landscape]{article}

\usepackage{etex}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds,fadings}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}%[show background grid]

\tikzstyle{every node}=[font=\scriptsize]

\begin{axis}[/tikz/ybar, 
ybar legend, 
xtick align=outside,
ymin=0,
axis y line*=left,
bar width=1.5cm,
axis x line*=left,
 nodes near coords= {
    \pgfmathfloattofixed{\pgfplotspointmeta} 
    \num[
        scientific-notation = fixed,
        fixed-exponent = 0,
        round-mode = places,
        round-precision = 2,
        exponent-product=\cdot
    ]{\pgfmathresult}},
enlarge x limits=false,
grid=none,  
axis on top, 
height=6cm,
title={},
xlabel={Intervalos de Clase},
ylabel=\rotatebox{-90}{$F_{i}$},
symbolic x coords={$<11.5$,$11.5$,$14.5$,$17.5$,$20.5$,$23.5$,$>23.5$},
xtick={$11.5$,$14.5$,$17.5$,$20.5$,$23.5$},
minor x tick num=1, 
width=\textwidth]
\addplot[white,fill=white] coordinates {($<11.5$,0) ($>23.5$,0)};
\addplot[green!80!black,fill=green!40!white] coordinates {($11.5$,0.32)($14.5$,0.56)   ($17.5$,0.64) ($20.5$,0.76) ($23.5$,1.00)};
\addplot[thick,color=blue, sharp plot] coordinates {($11.5$,0.32) ($14.5$,0.56) ($17.5$,0.64) ($20.5$,0.76) ($23.5$,1.00)};
\legend{}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}           

\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay]
\node[above] (red) at (0.8,2) {\footnotesize\textcolor{magenta}{Ojiva}};
\node (reddot) at (4.1,3.0) {};
\path[->, color=magenta, line width=0.75] (red) edge [out = 50, in = 145] (reddot);
\node[right] (gre) at (11.5,2.75) {\footnotesize\textcolor{cyan}{Histograma}};
\node (gredot) at (10,2.9) {};
\path[->, color=cyan, line width=0.75] (gre) edge [out = 160, in = 45] (gredot);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: better answer. I am deleting mine.